# NLog change eventlog target to something else than Application

Tags: c#, nlog, event-viewer

I Changed the target log from Application to "xxxx".
I removed the Source using powersheel
and the created it under "xxxx".
when i write event's it doesn't appear anywhere.

```
target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("eventlog");
mode = config.RUN_MODE;
LogManager.Configuration.RemoveTarget("console");
((NLog.Targets.EventLogTarget)target).Log = "xxxx";
LoggingConfiguration loggingConfiguration = new LoggingConfiguration();
var asyncFileTarget = new AsyncTargetWrapper(target);
loggingConfiguration.AddTarget("eventlog", asyncFileTarget);
LogManager.Configuration = loggingConfiguration;
LogManager.Configuration.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, target, mode, true);
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

I removed and added using powershell the new log and source (the "xxxx" log was created):

```
Remove-EventLog -Source "mySource" 
New-EventLog -LogName xxxx -Source "mySource code here
```

Comment: PS: you could use `target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<NLog.Targets.EventLogTarget>("eventlog");` - that saves a cast

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new event log, something the server needs a reboot. Also makes sure that the account has write access to the event log.

Also important, assigning the Configuration property to LogManager will activate the config, so it's advised to add the rules first.

So not:

```
LogManager.Configuration = loggingConfiguration;
LogManager.Configuration.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, target, mode, true);
```

But:

```
loggingConfiguration.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, target, mode, true);
LogManager.Configuration = loggingConfiguration; // activates config
```

If there are still issues, I would recommend to follow the [NLog Troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting)

Comment: i tried all, i  even change the log="xxxx" in the app.config but it still doesn't write to the new event log